# Mysql PHP: Calculate multiple mysql column query

Tags: php, mysql, calculated-columns

I have an table `tbl_1` that store db like

```
    value1   value2   value3   calculated

    10       20       30       null
```

and make TextInput variable like this

```
$a = value1
$b = value2
$c = value3
```

I need to know the query like:

`UPDATE tbl_1 SET calculated VALUE SUM(( $a * 2 / 10 ) + ( $b * 3 / 10 ) + ( $c * 5 / 10 ))`

but the query doesnt work for me...
or any other method to calculate with it?

The database should be like :

```
    value1   value2   value3   calculated

    10       20       30       23
    22       33       51       39.8
```

Anyone can help me?

Here's my full source code that im work with
http://codepad.org/j9zveRdO `line 431`

Comment: Note: without a `WHERE` clause `UPDATE` will update every row in the table.

Comment: Isn't there some way you could learn basic SQL syntax without having to ask here? Can't you just read the MySQL documentation? It has syntax descriptions and numerous examples. Or read turorials?

Comment: sorry, but im confuse to include the basic syntax to my source code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE tbl_1 
SET calculated = ( $a * 2 / 10 ) + ( $b * 3 / 10 ) + ( $c * 5 / 10 )
```

Comment: @GothicJymz:- What is your source code and what doesnt work? You have to explain a bit more? What is the error msg?

Comment: im not seing any error, but the column still doesnt change 
check my full source, i've already edit my question

Comment: Why would you use SUM and + together?

Answer (score 1):

we don't need to use input variable if values are available in table each row. Use field name.

```
 UPDATE tbl_1 SET calculated=( value1 * 2 / 10 ) + ( value2 * 3 / 10 ) + ( value3 * 5 /
 10 )
```

Comment: but the value there are changeable, i've array all to be 1 editable table

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
UPDATE tbl_1 SET `calculated` = (( `value1` * 2 / 10 ) + (`value2` * 3 / 10 ) 
                                + ( `value3` * 5 / 10 ));
```

It'll read your fields i.e. value1, value2, value3 and update the column calculated based on the calculation